# Performance Center (LoadRunner) 11.0 protocol bundle, SOA (Service Test Vuser) and SAML security technoloy

Tags: soa, saml, loadrunner

Does the LoadRunner/Performance center SOA Protocol (including the Service Test VUser) support testing webservices using SAML tokens in the requests?

Googling this gives me little information about the subject...

My question being:
Given that I have the Web 2.0 protocol bundle including SOA protocol, that again includes the Service Test VUser, would I be able to record and play back scripts running against web services using SAML tokens as part of the request(s)?

[Does the Service Test VUser support SAML tokens in the request?]